# Python 3 List Comprehension remove tuples from list

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have to solve a task for university. I have 4 given lists and I have to count the possible variations of burgers that can be made under some restrictions.

```
breads = ["Weissbrot", "Vollkorn", "Dinkel", "Speckbrot"]
patties = ["Wildschwein", "Rind", "Halloumi", "Aubergine"]
souces = ["Kaese", "Knoblauch", "Curry"]
toppings = ["Kopfsalat", "Bacon", "Tomate"]
```

My code so far:

```
i = "bottom, patty, souce, topping, top"

burger = [i for bottom in breads
          for top in breads
          for patty in patties
          for souce in souces
          for topping in toppings
          if bottom != top
          if i != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine", "Kaese", "Bacon", "Weissbrot")]

print(len(burger))
```

The restrictions:

The finished burger needs to have the structure (bottom, patty, souce, topping, top). I safed this under the variable 'i'. Bottom and top must have different bread. I solved this with `if bottom != top`.

Mixing Aubergine with Speckbrot, Kaese or Bacon and Halloumi with Speckbrot or Bacon is not allowed. I tried to sovle this with `if i != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine", "Kaese", "Bacon", "Weissbrot")` but its obviously not correct.

Furthermore, if bottom and top are swapped and the rest stays the same this counts as 1 burger and not 2. I have no plan how to solve this yet.

Sorry for the german words, i can translate it if needed.

Many thanks in advance

EDIT: The correct answer is 138 variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with the variable `i`, which doesn't work the way you seem to want it to. It is not a substitute for naming five variables. It's just a string that happens to have the variable names in it.

This would be a valid comprehension, though I suspect the restriction from the last `if` clause is a lot more narrow than you want (it forbids exactly one combination).

```
burger = [(bottom, patty, souce, topping, top)
          for bottom in breads
          for top in breads
          for patty in patties
          for souce in souces
          for topping in toppings
          if bottom != top
          if (bottom, patty, souce, topping, top) !=
             ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine", "Kaese", "Bacon", "Weissbrot")]
```

Comment: I added 
`if (bottom, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
if (top, patty) != ("Speckbrot", "Aubergine")
if (patty, souce) != ("Aubergine", "Kaese")
if (patty, topping) != ("Aubergine", "Bacon")
if (patty, bottom) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
if (patty, top) != ("Halloumi", "Speckbrot")
if (patty, topping) != ("Halloumi", "Bacon")` and it works but is there a nicer way to do this?

Comment: You might be able to combine some of the conditions with boolean algebra (e.g. `and` expressions), but it may not be easy or that much neater. Normally you wouldn't do something complicated like that in a single statement.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. Do you have an idea how to implement the last restriction?

Answer (score 0):

First, in this case you probably shouldn't be using list comprehension. List comprehension is for smaller things, and this is far too messy. This is probably the best way to do it (using for loops). In the code below, count will be the total number and choices are all possible burgers.

```
choices = []
count = 0
for b in breads:
    for p in patties:
        for s in souces:
            for t in toppings:
                temp = [b, p, s, t]
                #add restrictions here
                choices.append(temp)
                count += 1
```

print (choices, count)

Comment: Unfortunately, I must use list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension, this works

```
choices = [[b, p, s, t] for b in breads for p in patties for s in souces for t in toppings] #add restrections (if [b,p, s, t] !=)
```

print (choices)